# NoSuchElementException in nested for each loop

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, boolean

I have problem with function checking collision. No matter what I do it throws NoSuchElementException. Here it is:

```
public boolean isColliding(Pixel a) {
    if((a.x + a.size/2 <= x - size/2 &&
        a.x - a.size/2 >= x - size/2 ||
         a.x + a.size/2 <= x + size/2 &&
          a.x - a.size/2 >= x + size/2) &&
      (a.y + a.size/2 <= y - size/2 &&
        a.y - a.size/2 >= y - size/2 ||
         a.y + a.size/2 <= y + size/2 &&
          a.y - a.size/2 >= y + size/2) 
            ) { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

Here is whole code:

[Main.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62638687/part/Main.txt)

[Particle.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62638687/part/Particle.txt)

[ParticleHandler.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62638687/part/ParticleHandler.txt)

[Pixel.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62638687/part/Pixel.txt)

Comment: Provide error stack trace for NoSuchElementException.

Comment: `if (a) {return true;} else {return false;}` can be reduced to `return a;`. Where's the stack trace? Where is the for each loop?

Comment: Post relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question Clearly more than your initial few lines of quoted code are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's ya problem (`Main.java`):

```
for(Iterator<Pixel> iterator2 = pixel.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();){
    if( iterator != iterator2 ){
        licz.field(iterator2.next());
        try{ 
            if( px.isColliding(iterator2.next())) { temporary++; } 
        } catch(Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

`iterator2.next()` is called inside a loop without `hasNext()` check.

Also this:

```
if(damnLongCondition) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

Can (and should) be reduced to:

```
return damnLongCondition;
```

Comment: Ok, making temporary Pixel object and assigning iterator2.next to it fixed this problem. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your error probably comes from here:

```
for(Iterator<Pixel> iterator2 = pixel.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();){
if( iterator != iterator2 ){
    licz.field(iterator2.next());
try{ 
        if( px.isColliding(iterator2.next())) { temporary++; } 
} catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

You are invoking iterator2.next() a second time in the loop without verifying it still has a next value.